# Prevent Ant modal blocking background access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I'm using Ant modal in my react application, would appreciate if I can know the way to prevent modal popup disabling access to the background content. to remove the div tag it puts on top of the background.

regards

Comment: Did you try `mask={false}`?

Comment: yes, it only removes the mask (dark shade ), still prevents me from accessing the background text etc..

Comment: See my answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclamer: I haven't ever worked with that library.

---

Any of its `props` doesn't seem to help but I did manage to hack it with CSS.

Be aware that future library updates could break this hack.

```
.ant-modal-mask {
  background: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.ant-modal-wrap {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.ant-modal {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```